# Validate GRPC request parameters : .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

What is the best approach to validate the GRPC input request? In the below example, we need to validate both fields, as these are required fields.
For example:

```
message AudienceRequest {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 1;
}
```